# Datatables Export to CSV and Excel File Extension Missing

Tags: datatables, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I followed the following [example](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html). However, whenever I click on the CSV and Excel file export button I only get a file without its extension. It would be cumbersome for my final users to manually add the file extension so I was wondering if there is something that needs to be fixed. I have already read the the source code in the example but I have not found anything different. The source code to create the table is pretty straightforward.

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ]
} );
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that I needed to add the title and extension options to the table code. If any of those is missing I would get a file without the appropriate extension.

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'copy', 
        {
            extend: 'csv',
            text: 'csv',
            extension: '.csv',
            exportOptions: {
                modifier: {
                    page: 'current'
                }
            },
            title: 'table'
        }, 
        'pdf', 
        'print',
        {
            extend: 'excel',
            text: 'excel',
            extension: '.xlsx',
            exportOptions: {
                modifier: {
                    page: 'current'
                }
            },
            title: 'table'
        }
    ]
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

A solutions,

```
 "aButtons": [
                {
                "oSelectorOpts": { filter: 'applied', order: 'current' },
                "sExtends": "copy",
                "sButtonText": "Copiar en Portapapeles"
                },
                {
                    "oSelectorOpts": { filter: 'applied', order: 'current' },
                    "sExtends": "xls",
                    "sButtonText": "Excel",
                    "sFileName": "*.xls" // <-- ADD THIS LINE

                },

                {
                    "oSelectorOpts": { filter: 'applied', order: 'current' },
                    "sExtends": "pdf",
                    "sPdfOrientation": "landscape",
                    "sPdfMessage": "RegES - Reportes ", 
                },
                "print"
            ]
        },
```